# How to start a globally installed module as an application from the code?

Tags: node.js, windows, process, npm, launch

## Short version

Why does it fail to run a global module from the code if `cmd` extension is not specified? How can I fix it without changing the launching code?

```
D:\Temp\Supertemp>node --version
v0.12.4

D:\Temp\Supertemp>phantomjs --version
1.9.8

D:\Temp\Supertemp>phantomjs.cmd --version
1.9.8

D:\Temp\Supertemp>node -e "var res=require('child_process').spawnSync('phantomjs',['--version']); console.log(res.stdout+'', res.error);"
null { [Error: spawnSync ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawnSync' }

D:\Temp\Supertemp>node -e "var res=require('child_process').spawnSync('phantomjs.cmd',['--version']); console.log(res.stdout+'', res.error);"
1.9.8
 undefined

D:\Temp\Supertemp>
```

## Full version

There is a globally installed module, for example `phantomjs`

```
npm install -g phantomjs
```

Npm have added a file for starting this module from the command line

```
%appdata%\npm\phantomjs.cmd
```

The corresponding folder is specified in `%path%` enviroment variable. The module can be launched from any folder:

```
D:\Temp\Supertemp>phantomjs
phantomjs> ^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?
^C
```

The problem occures when I try to lunch it from nodejs code:

```
{ '0':
   { [Error: spawn phantomjs ENOENT]
     code: 'ENOENT',
     errno: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'spawn phantomjs',
     path: 'phantomjs' } }
```

Last time I saw this problem in my own code and solved it via explicit extension specifiing: launching `phantomjs.cmd` works fine, and just `phantomjs` fails. Just to remind, both ways are fine if stating from console.

Now this problem happend inside of installed module `html-inspector`.

How can I solve this problem without changing the module's sources?

---

PS: [Same question in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/434183/178988).